# Extract 2 lists input into a text file

Tags: list, extract

I would need to save the input of two lists into a text file such that I can retrieve the input by opening the text file.

x=[x1,x2,x3]

y=[y1,y2,y3]

I want to saved it this way in the text file

[x1,x2,x3]

[y1,y2,y3]

I tried to saved the files but it kept giving me

[[x1,x2,x3],[y1,y2,y3]] instead.

is there a way to make the first input and second input on two separate lines?

### the code I used to extract it

lines = []

xcoord=[]

ycoord=[]

with open('lists.txt') as f:

```
lines = f.readlines()
```

count1 = 0

for line in lines:

```
xcoord=lines[count1]

ycoord=lines[count1+1]
```

x=(list(map(float, ycoord)))
y=(list(map(float, ycoord)))

##And this is the error I got

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '['

Answer (score 0):

Just add `\n` newline character where you want to insert newline.

```
x=['x1','x2','x3']

y=['y1','y2','y3']

with open('lists.txt', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(str(x)+'\n')
    f.write(str(y))
f.close()
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help! Can I ask does this write function only works for str? As my input is actually a float.

Comment: I think it will work with float numbers list also. for that too we need to convert the list to str while writing to file and then add a new line character. since we can only add two strings i.e. similar data types.

Comment: hey beegaou, can I ask after I save it to the text file using str, is there a way I can extract it  based on the same form as the input?

I did try converting it back to the float using list but it kept saying unable to convert string to float.

Here's my code:

lines = []
xcoord=[]
ycoord=[]
with open('lists.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
count1 = 0
for line in lines:
    xcoord=lines[count1]
    ycoord=lines[count1+1]
    
x=(list(map(float, ycoord)))
y=(list(map(float, ycoord)))

and i got this error:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '['

Comment: 'str' is just used here to convert the data type of list. we can only write string to the txt file. thats why we had to convert list to string using 'str'. if we want to read text from file we need to open file in read mode and use 'read' function.  Just google search "read write file in python" you will get many articles for that.

Comment: I am trying to read the txt file and extract the two lists again. And use the two list to run the a turtle code.

Comment: I am doing something like Input x and y coordinates into two separate list, use turtle to draw a graph, save the x and y coordinates into a txt file and then able to use the txt file to ask turtle to draw the same graph again (without having to input the coordinates)

Comment: I tried to read that. but I am also getting the same issue. The output is in str type. and unable to convert to original list. Trying to figure out.

Comment: I think it will better if we could originally write individual coordinates ( without brackets [ ] ) in the txt file. by that, it would be easy to convert back to float numbers.

Comment: Hey WyzPanda, I managed to get what I wanted using the individual coordinates. Thanks alot for the guidance!